# Nginx - Forward HTTP AUTH - User

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, jenkins, http-basic-authentication

I have some trouble with Nginx and Jenkins (Hudson). I am trying to use Nginx as Reverse Proxy for the Jenkins instance with HTTP Basic Authentication.

It works so far, but i have no idea how to pass the Header with the Authentication Username.

```
location / {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/.htpasswd;
  sendfile off;

  proxy_pass         http://192.168.178.102:8080;
  proxy_redirect     default;
  proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-User $http_authorization; 
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

  #this is the maximum upload size
  client_max_body_size       10m;
  client_body_buffer_size    128k;

  proxy_connect_timeout      90;
  proxy_send_timeout         90;
  proxy_read_timeout         90;             
  proxy_buffer_size          4k;
  proxy_buffers              4 32k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
  proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}
```

Comment: Note you probably want an extra 'd' in "X-Forwared-User".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try adding this directives to your location block

```
proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
```

Comment: This header is passing: Username: Basic YXJuZTpraWxsZXI, not the correct name from http auth (;

Comment: This must be base64 encoded string http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#cite_note-8 try to decoding it

Comment: Authorization header must be base64 encoded header, yes. But that is not what the question is about. The question is about passing auth username in headers, not full authorization header.

Comment: ``YXJuZTpraWxsZXI`` decodes to ``arne:killer`` - nice example @opHASnoNAME :-)

Comment: pass_header and set_header...? isn't this two times more or less the same effect? Both should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: i think proxy_pass_header is not required, but it should be tested again.

Comment: Did anybody test by now, whether `proxy_pass_header` is really required here?

Answer (score 11):

To get this to work with Jenkins reverse proxy auth plugin:

```
proxy_set_header Authorization "";
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-User $remote_user;
```

If you don't reset `Authorization` header, nginx will forward that by default, and when enabling reverse proxy auth plugin, Jenkins (jetty) will try to re-authenticate the user, and fails on that.

nginx version 1.12.1, Jenkins 2.113.

Comment: THANK YOU!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  MUCH appreciated.