# Nginx rewrite and proxying

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

I am trying to combine these 2 Nginx location definitions into 1

```
 location /v1/login {
     proxy_pass      http://upstream/v1/login;
     proxy_redirect     off;

     proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
     proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
     proxy_pass_header Authorization;
     }

 location /v1/logout {
     proxy_pass      http://upstream/v1/logout;
     proxy_redirect     off;

     proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
     proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
     proxy_pass_header Authorization;
     }
```

So I figured something like this should do the job

```
    location ^~ /v1/(login|logout) {
            rewrite ^/v1/(.*)$ /v1/$1 break;
            proxy_pass      http://upstream;
            proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;

    }
```

But for the life of me I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?
I have tried every possible combination of rewrite regexes.

Comment: Why you want to combine them? Shiw full configuration

Comment: @AlexeyTen: Because I am trying to clean up and consolidate the config and consolidating these two definitions into one seems like a thing that should be easy. Whoever put the current config together thought that adding 150+ separate `location` definitions in no particular order was the way to go, so the config has become unmanageable. I've consolidated everything else and it is working, except this particular part.

Comment: What king of requests do you need to handle? Is `/v1/login` (or logout) enough, or do you need all paths starting with it, like `/v1/login/something.html`? Also, `^~` symbols do not work for regex matching, use just `~` for case-sensitive match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one?

```
location ~ ^/v1/(login|logout) {
    proxy_pass http://upstream/v1/$1;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
}
```

***Edit:***

You may also add the following directive along with your `proxy_pass_header Authorization;` directive:

```
proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
```

Comment: Yep. Does not work either. I can't understand why. Spent way too much time on this already.

Comment: what is the result of this? does Nginx show any errors when you reload it? what do you see when you navigate to `/v1/login` or `/v1/logout` ?

Comment: It hits the js script which throws logs a console error `if( config.url.indexOf("/v1/") == 0  && responseError.status == 401){`. I get a 401 in nginx too, because this is the error the `upstream` java app throws. Unfortunately there are no useful logs from the java app.

Comment: @solefald You can try to access Java app directly, by navigating to `http://yourdomain.com:3000/v1/login` where `3000` is a port number which is listened by Java app, to make sure that the problem is on Nginx side. Alse you may try [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/511206/nginx-forward-http-auth-user) solution

Comment: Aaaand your edit solved the problem! Thank you so much! I was losing my mind here over something that simple.

Comment: @solefald happy to help. good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this simple one?

```
location /v1/ {
    proxy_pass      http://upstream/v1/;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: There are other `/v1/blah` locations that go to different places, so I can't just send them all there, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the complete URL to `proxy_pass`. Try something like this:

```
location ~ ^/v1/(login|logout) {
    proxy_pass http://upstream;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: Does not work either, unfortunately.